# Processing doesn't respond to arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, signal-processing

First of all if I make a wrong sentence this is because my main language isn't english.
I have a homework so i am trying to make a radar with Arduino IDE and Processing. I found and wrote the codes from internet but processing does not respond to ultrasonic sensor and i tought maybe it isn't detecting the serial port.
Code from Processing:

```
import processing.serial.*; // imports library for serial communication
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; // imports library for reading the data from the serial port
import java.io.IOException;

Serial myPort; // defines Object Serial
// defubes variables
String angle="";
String distance="";
String data="";
String noObject;
float pixsDistance;
int iAngle, iDistance;
int index1=0;
int index2=0;
PFont orcFont;

void setup() {
  
 size (1600, 900); // ***CHANGE THIS TO YOUR SCREEN RESOLUTION***
 smooth();
 myPort = new Serial(this,"COM3", 9600); // starts the serial communication
 myPort.bufferUntil('.'); // reads the data from the serial port up to the character '.'. So actually it reads this: angle,distance.
 orcFont = loadFont("Calibri-Bold-48.vlw");
}

void draw() {
  
  fill(98,245,31);
  textFont(orcFont);
  // simulating motion blur and slow fade of the moving line
  noStroke();
  fill(0,4); 
  rect(0, 0, width, height-height*0.065); 
  
  fill(98,245,31); // green color
  // calls the functions for drawing the radar
  drawRadar(); 
  drawLine();
  drawObject();
  drawText();
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) { // starts reading data from the Serial Port
  // reads the data from the Serial Port up to the character '.' and puts it into the String variable "data".
  data = myPort.readStringUntil('.');
  data = data.substring(0,data.length()-1);
  
  index1 = data.indexOf(","); // find the character ',' and puts it into the variable "index1"
  angle= data.substring(0, index1); // read the data from position "0" to position of the variable index1 or thats the value of the angle the Arduino Board sent into the Serial Port
  distance= data.substring(index1+1, data.length()); // read the data from position "index1" to the end of the data pr thats the value of the distance
  
  // converts the String variables into Integer
  iAngle = parseInt(angle);
  iDistance = parseInt(distance);
}

void drawRadar() {
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2,height-height*0.074); // moves the starting coordinats to new location
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(2);
  stroke(98,245,31);
  // draws the arc lines
  arc(0,0,(width-width*0.0625),(width-width*0.0625),PI,TWO_PI);
  arc(0,0,(width-width*0.27),(width-width*0.27),PI,TWO_PI);
  arc(0,0,(width-width*0.479),(width-width*0.479),PI,TWO_PI);
  arc(0,0,(width-width*0.687),(width-width*0.687),PI,TWO_PI);
  // draws the angle lines
  line(-width/2,0,width/2,0);
  line(0,0,(-width/2)*cos(radians(30)),(-width/2)*sin(radians(30)));
  line(0,0,(-width/2)*cos(radians(60)),(-width/2)*sin(radians(60)));
  line(0,0,(-width/2)*cos(radians(90)),(-width/2)*sin(radians(90)));
  line(0,0,(-width/2)*cos(radians(120)),(-width/2)*sin(radians(120)));
  line(0,0,(-width/2)*cos(radians(150)),(-width/2)*sin(radians(150)));
  line((-width/2)*cos(radians(30)),0,width/2,0);
  popMatrix();
}

void drawObject() {
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2,height-height*0.074); // moves the starting coordinats to new location
  strokeWeight(9);
  stroke(255,10,10); // red color
  pixsDistance = iDistance*((height-height*0.1666)*0.025); // covers the distance from the sensor from cm to pixels
  // limiting the range to 40 cms
  if(iDistance<40){
    // draws the object according to the angle and the distance
  line(pixsDistance*cos(radians(iAngle)),-pixsDistance*sin(radians(iAngle)),(width-width*0.505)*cos(radians(iAngle)),-(width-width*0.505)*sin(radians(iAngle)));
  }
  popMatrix();
}

void drawLine() {
  pushMatrix();
  strokeWeight(9);
  stroke(30,250,60);
  translate(width/2,height-height*0.074); // moves the starting coordinats to new location
  line(0,0,(height-height*0.12)*cos(radians(iAngle)),-(height-height*0.12)*sin(radians(iAngle))); // draws the line according to the angle
  popMatrix();
}

void drawText() { // draws the texts on the screen
  
  pushMatrix();
  if(iDistance>40) {
  noObject = "Out of Range";
  }
  else {
  noObject = "In Range";
  }
  fill(0,0,0);
  noStroke();
  rect(0, height-height*0.0648, width, height);
  fill(98,245,31);
  textSize(25);
  
  text("10cm",width-width*0.3854,height-height*0.0833);
  text("20cm",width-width*0.281,height-height*0.0833);
  text("30cm",width-width*0.177,height-height*0.0833);
  text("40cm",width-width*0.0729,height-height*0.0833);
  textSize(40);
  text("Obje: " + noObject, width-width*0.875, height-height*0.0277);
  text("Açı: " + iAngle +" °", width-width*0.48, height-height*0.0277);
  text("Mesafe: ", width-width*0.26, height-height*0.0277);
  if(iDistance<40) {
  text("        " + iDistance +" cm", width-width*0.225, height-height*0.0277);
  }
  textSize(25);
  fill(98,245,60);
  translate((width-width*0.4994)+width/2*cos(radians(30)),(height-height*0.0907)-width/2*sin(radians(30)));
  rotate(-radians(-60));
  text("30°",0,0);
  resetMatrix();
  translate((width-width*0.503)+width/2*cos(radians(60)),(height-height*0.0888)-width/2*sin(radians(60)));
  rotate(-radians(-30));
  text("60°",0,0);
  resetMatrix();
  translate((width-width*0.507)+width/2*cos(radians(90)),(height-height*0.0833)-width/2*sin(radians(90)));
  rotate(radians(0));
  text("90°",0,0);
  resetMatrix();
  translate(width-width*0.513+width/2*cos(radians(120)),(height-height*0.07129)-width/2*sin(radians(120)));
  rotate(radians(-30));
  text("120°",0,0);
  resetMatrix();
  translate((width-width*0.5104)+width/2*cos(radians(150)),(height-height*0.0574)-width/2*sin(radians(150)));
  rotate(radians(-60));
  text("150°",0,0);
  popMatrix(); 
}
```

Code from Arduino IDE:

```
#include <Servo.h>   // servo motor kütüphanesi
#define trigPin 4    // ultrasonik sensör trig pini
#define echoPin 3    // ultrasonik sensör echo pini
Servo servoMotor;     // servo motor nesnesi
int angle = 0;        // servo motor açısı
long duration, distance;  // ultrasonik sensör mesafesi

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  // seri haberleşme hızı
  servoMotor.attach(9); // servo motor pin numarası
}

void loop() {
  for(angle = 0; angle < 180; angle += 10){  // servo motor açıları
    servoMotor.write(angle);  // servo motoru hareket ettir
    delay(200);               // bekleme süresi
    distance = getDistance(); // mesafe ölçümü
    Serial.print(angle);      // açıyı yazdır
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(distance); // mesafeyi yazdır
  }
}

long getDistance(){ // ultrasonik sensör mesafe ölçümü
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = duration / 58.2;
  return distance;
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: the processing sketch is irrelevant here ... open the Arduino IDE serial monitor to determine if the correct data is being sent by the Arduino

Comment: can you give me more details. Like i said i don't know english too much and i am new to arduino ide. And there is only the angle in the serial monitor

Answer (score 1):

Your processing code is looking for something that ends in a '.'

Your arduino code is sending angle,distnace[new line]

So either change your processing code to look for '\n' (the new line character) rather than '.' or change your arduino code to add a . to the end:

```
Serial.print(angle);      // açıyı yazdır
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print(distance); // mesafeyi yazdır
Serial.print(".");
```